# How do these equations get derived?

Tags: area, parametric, arc-length

Please look at this webpage for reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html

**Go to line 7 to 15 on that webpage.** Line 7 and 8 show 2 parametric equations. These have been rewritten as in line 12 and 13. I understand how this has been done. But I want to know how these parametric equations (line 12 and 13) have been used to get the arc length and the area equations (line 14 and 15 respectively).

I have tried using the arc length formula:

[image]

I rearranged to get the radius in terms of S and theta. Then I substitute that into the area equation:

[image]

But that gives me the area in terms of theta. However, on the webpage, there is no angle or theta.

How should I do this? If there is something I am mission **or these is another, better way to do this**, please tell me.

Sorry for my incompetence and thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

**By "LINE" I mean the numbers that are on the right side of the page in brackets**

Comment: May refer to my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859911/hypocycloid-direction-of-circles-rotation-and-revolution/1860113#1860113)

Comment: @NgChungTak I don't think that answers my question. I already have the parametric equations of the hypocycloid. They are on line 7 and 8. **I want to know how the equation in line 14 and 15 came to be.**

Comment: Line $7$ reads $$\theta=\frac{a-b}{b} \phi$$ which is equation $(2).$   Please specify which **equations** you don't understand instead of which **lines**, ***THAT'S HELP!***

Comment: @NgChungTak Look at my edit

Comment: @NgChungTak Sorry for not making it clear before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that hypocycloid is simply connected when $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}=n=3,4,5, \ldots$

Now
\begin{align*}
  x &= \frac{a}{n}[(n-1)\cos t+\cos (n-1)t] \\
  y &= \frac{a}{n}[(n-1)\sin t-\sin (n-1)t] \\
  x' &= \frac{a(n-1)}{n} [-\sin t-\sin (n-1)t] \\
  y' &= \frac{a(n-1)}{n} [\cos t-\cos (n-1)t] \\
  x'^2+y'^2 &=
  \frac{a^2(n-1)^2}{n^2} (2-2\cos nt)] \\
  &= \frac{4a^2(n-1)^2}{n^2} \sin^2 \frac{nt}{2} \\
  ds &= \frac{2a(n-1)}{n} \left| \sin \frac{nt}{2} \right| dt \\
  P &= n\int_{0}^{2\pi/n} \frac{2a(n-1)}{n} \sin \frac{nt}{2} \, dt \\
  &= 2a(n-1) \left[ -\frac{2}{n} \cos \frac{nt}{2} \right]_{0}^{2\pi/n} \\
  &= \frac{8a(n-1)}{n} \\
  A &= \oint_{C} x\, dy \\
  &= \frac{a^2(n-1)}{n^2} \times \pi [(n-1)-1]
     \quad \quad \text{(see the note below)} \\
  &= \frac{\pi a^2(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2}
\end{align*}

> Note that
>     $$x\, dy = \frac{a^2(n-1)}{n^2}
>   [(n-1)\cos^2 t+(2-n)\cos t \cos (n-1)t-\cos^2 (n-1)t] \, dt$$
>
> By $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos nt \, \cos mt \, dt = \pi \delta_{n,m}$$
>   only the square terms in $x\, dy$ survive after integration.
>
> For the area of hypocycloid with other values of $n$, see another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342799/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-region-with-a-closed-plane-curve-boundary).

Comment: Interesting answer. Besides, I had a look at your answer dated July 15th. May I ask you how you do you realize your animations ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, The animation was made by **Geogebra** which is a freeware and free to [download](https://www.geogebra.org/download).  Thanks to your visit anyways.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that Geogebra permit animations...

Comment: @NgChungTak It's a very good answer but can you explain what is "ds" and "P". Also, that integral sign with the circle and the letter C (for the area), what is that? Sorry, I don't know what that symbol means or what its called.

Comment: @NgChungTak Also, why did you square and then add the x and y parametric equations? What is the reason for doing this? I looked online and some of them said do this: (Go to think link)

`http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}Y(\theta)(\frac{d}{d\theta}X(\theta))d\theta`

Does this work?

Comment: $ds$ is differential of arclength, $$ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2} dt$$
$P$ is perimeter, $$P=\int ds=\int \sqrt{\left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2+\left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2}dt$$
$C$ is a close contour/curve, usinig Green's theorem, $$A=\oint_{C} x dy = -\oint_{C} y dx = \frac{1}{2} \oint_{C} x dy-y dx$$

Comment: @NgChungTak Why did you square root to get ds. Can't you just get the derivative of `http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?{x}'^{2}&plus;{y}'^{2}`. Also, did you need to find the perimeter to get the Area?

Comment: @NgChungTak Also, why do you use the close curve integral instead of normal integral?

Comment: Either $x(y)$ or $y(x)$ is multi-valued.  A useful [link](http://www.numericalexpert.com/blog/area_calculation/)

Comment: There're no correlation among the **perimeter** of arbitrary close curve $C$ and its **area**.  However ,the area is maximized when $C$ is a circle, please see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19997/a-proof-of-the-isoperimetric-inequality-how-does-it-work).  Detail for arc length, please read [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArcLength.html).  By the way, do borrow and read more reference books or texts on calculus in your school library.

Comment: @NgChungTak Thanks for this so far but is there a way to get to the Area equation without using Green's Theorem? I am not at that high level of mathematics to be able to understand that. Online I found way which differentiated the y equation and multiplied it by the x equation. I would then integrate that from 0 to 2pi. Here is that website:http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx

Comment: @NgChungTak **OR even better would be:** if I could use the original parametric equations (Line 7 and 8 on the wolfram website) and then use the method shown here (differentiat the y equation and multiply it by the x equation): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx
Doing that, is there some way to get to the Area equation?